# Is there a way to use Conditional Formatting on non-customized web parts using SPD 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

On web part s as such (as shown on the image), is there a away to use conditional formatting? I know if I use a custom list I can use Conditional Formatting. Is there a away around to trick it and get Conditional Formatting un-greyed and use it to format the fields?

Using this on a calendar would be fantastic as well.

[image]

Comment: No, you can't do this in designer on the default view. However, it's extremely easy to create a custom form with the exact same info as the default form. Is there a reason you can't create a custom form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not do it via SP designer without customization but you can do it via jquery  or  embedded script editor after converting List view to Data view as mentioned below

- Edit Newform as the advanced mode .
- From the above ribbon > Insert new form > custom list form .
  [image]
- the list fields now are shown within the table
- try to use conditional formatting from the above ribbon

Or use the following Jquery code for a sample of conditional formatting,

```
<script src="/Style%20Library/js/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"><span id="ms-rterangecursor-start"></span><span id="ms-rterangecursor-end"></span></script><script>
        $(document).ready(function(){     
            $Text = $("td .ms-vb2:contains('yes')");
            $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#FFFF66");
        }); </script> 
    <style>
    .ms-number {
    text-align: center ! important;
    margin-top: -16px ! important;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: I recommend making a backup of the original newform.aspx if you're going to customize the default instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thank you M.Qassas. Brilliant. If I may ask briefly, would that Jquery code work for calendars, as you know they cannot be turned into data view or at least I think they can't. Cheers.

Thank you Erin for the reminder.